# how to see which process owns a python thread

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

My understanding from multi-threading has been that one process (cpu core) can have multiple threads running with it.

So far in python when I want to check which thread is calling a function, I print the following inside the function:

```
print('current thread:', threading.current_thread())
```

but this only tells me which thread. Is there a way to also show which process owns this thread and print it?

Comment: Are you mixing up the words "process" and "processor"?

Comment: @AKX , not sure, I call it process based on the explanation here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads are owned by the process that starts them. You can get the process ID with `os.getpid()`.

The process ID won't change between threads:

```
>>> import os
>>> import threading
>>>
>>> def print_process_id():
...   print(threading.current_thread(), os.getpid())
...
>>>
>>> threading.Thread(target=print_process_id).start()
<Thread(Thread-1, started 123145410715648)> 62999
>>> threading.Thread(target=print_process_id).start()
<Thread(Thread-2, started 123145410715648)> 62999
>>> threading.Thread(target=print_process_id).start()
<Thread(Thread-3, started 123145410715648)> 62999
>>> threading.Thread(target=print_process_id).start()
<Thread(Thread-4, started 123145410715648)> 62999
>>>
```

If you're looking to know which physical/logical CPU core is currently running your code and you're on a supported platform, you could use the psutil module, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56431370/51685.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are simply subset of a process.

The information associated with a thread are stored in what is called Thread Control Block (TCB). This contains the following information

- Thread Identifier
- Stack Pointer
- Parent Process Pointer
- Thread's register
- Program counter

Since what you are interested in knowing is the process that the thread lives on.

```
import os
os.getpid()
```

Once you get the process id you can open the Task Manager or system monitor to get the name corresponding to the identifier gotten using `os.getpid()`
[Windows Task Manager Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfJvq.jpg)